# shorten awk command pipes

Tags: linux, awk

fairly new to using linux on shell.

I want to reduce the amount of pipes I used to extract the following data.

```
V       190917135635Z           1005    unknown /C=DE/ST=City/L=City/O=something/OU=Somewhat/CN=someserver.com/emailAddress=test@toast.com
```

My goal is to put the following values into a separate file

```
190917135635 someserver.com
```

The command I use right now is fairly long, piped and looks like this

```
grep -v '^R' $file | awk '{print $2, $6}' | awk -F'[=|/]' '{print $1, $3}' | awk '{print $1, $3}' |  awk -F 'Z ' '{print $1, $2}' > sdata.txt
```

(The file contains other lines starting with 'R' so I exclude those in my grep)

Is this a legit way of doing it?

Is there a way to get this in a shorter command?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the delimiter?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post samples of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: You can get rid of the grep entirely: `awk '/^[^R]/ { ... }' $file`

Comment: `awk -F '  +|Z *|=|/' '{print $2,$16}' file`?

Comment: `awk -F'[ \tZ=/]+' '!/^R/{print $2,$16}'`

Comment: Are you sure it is `awk '{print $2, $6}' ` and not `awk '{print $2, $5}' ` I only see 5 columns.

Comment: @kvantour when I removed the "real" data for the anonymous I removed a space in the name of the OU. My bad.

Comment: This has big implications and will invalidate the current accepted answer in some cases. Imagine any extra space in the large string. The field numbering will completely change. The answer of James brown is bulletproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk. Using `match` to find CN entry and `substr` to extract it for `print` to print, if it exists.

```
$ awk '!/^R/{
    print $2,
        (match($0,/CN=[^/]+/)?substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3):"")  # 3==length("CN=")
}' file
```

Output:

```
190917135635Z someserver.com
```

Comment: You forgot the exclusion of lines starting with `R`

Comment: This is by far the safest option. As we do not know how the final string realy looks like (sample data can look different from line to line), then a search for `CN` is by far the safest option. Much better than hardcoding field numbers with a random Field Separator.

Answer (score 1):

Looks some of your data fields are used as creating SSL certificates, thus many fields might contain SPACES, i.e. City, Organization Name etc. That's why you need many awk lines(???). Here is one way which might help you overcome these issues. So instead of transforming your existing code logic, the target is to find the domain name by searching the substring `CN=` and fetching its corresponding value.

```
awk  '
    !/^R/{
        start  = index($0, "CN=")+3
        end    = index(substr($0, start), "/")
        domain = end ? substr($0, start, end-1) : substr($0, start)
        print $2, domain
    }
' file.txt
```

Where:

- we use `index()` to find the start-position of the substring `CN=`, `+3` will be the starting point of the domain name
- then we search the next `/` to get the end-position of this domain. if it's at the end of the line, there will be no `/` and thus `end` will be '0'
- then we get the domain name between the substring `CN=` and the next '/' by using `substr($0, start, end-1)` or the end of line by using `substr($0, start)`.

A short version:

```
awk '!/^R/{s=index($0, "CN=")+3; e=index(substr($0, s), "/"); print $2, substr($0, s, e ? e-1 : 253)}' file.txt
```

where `253` is the longest possible domain name which might be enough to fit your needs.

**Update:**

Actually, it's much easier just use `match()`, but the point is the same:

```
awk '!/^R/{if(match($0, "/CN=([^/]*)")) print $2, substr($0, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-4)}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If this:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]/=]+' '!/^R/{print $2+0, $16}' file
190917135635 someserver.com
```

isn't all you need then updated your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Strictly considering that OP's Input_file is same as shown samples only. After seeing OP's samples one could try following.

```
awk -F"[ =/Z]" '!/^R/{print $8,$37}'  Input_file
```

---

---

For FUN :) in case one want to try in OP's approach then we could try following.

```
awk '
!/^R/{
  val=$2 OFS $5
  split(val,array,"[ /Z]")
  val1=array[1] OFS array[9] OFS array[10]
  split(val1,array1,"[ =]")
  print array1[1],array1[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you! This shortens it quite a bit. Like one comment mentioned, I had a little twist by removing a space to mask the data. I just put in your code with $38 and it spits out just what I wanted : )

Comment: @uptoya, please do mention here, for reason for removing this answer as correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed`:

`sed -E -n '/^R/d; s/^[A-Za-z]\s+([0-9]+)\s+[0-9]+\s+.*\/CN=(.*)\/.*/\1 \2/p' input_file > new_file`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$6` in the second `awk` command, that means your *5th* column has potentially space*s* inside unlike the sample data you showed, also it is extracting `CN=` part (CNAME?).

So here's a more compatible and more exact `sed` way which does not require GNU sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^R/!{' -e 's|^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]Z][^[:space:]Z]*\).*/CN=\([^/][^/]*\).*|\1 \2|p;}'
```

If you just want digits in the second column and it begins with digit, then you can change to use this:

```
sed -n -e '/^R/!{' -e 's|^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/CN=\([^/][^/]*\).*|\1 \2|p;}'
```

Comment: yes .. the real data had another space in between, thank you for pointing it out : )